# NSURLConnection performs slower than android

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using NSURLConnection. To call API the following is my code

```
NSData *aData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

It takes a long time to get the response. when i try using log the response is received but still the connection is not stopped when response received

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can implement AFNetworking. But to get JSON data from API also depends on server and internet speed.

Comment: Ok I will try this

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can try to implement by yourself URLConnection with your solution, which will be faster analogs and native solution. Good luck!

Comment: what is this URLConnection .. ?

Comment: It's abstract name, I try to explain approach to this work

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question